# Python: value > value returns true when it plainly isn't

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, boolean, max

I kept having errors raised while using a module, so I went to the line that was raising the exception and here it is:

```
elif value > max(self._intervals):
    raise Exception("\nERROR: Value Is Greater Than Maximum Element In Points List")
    return
```

This all occurs in a large loop, so I wanted to figure out which iteration of variables was causing it.  Turns out, 9 out of 14 of the iterations were causing errors.  So I adjusted the code to read:

```
elif value > max(self._intervals):
    print value
    print self._intervals
    print max(self._intervals)
    print value > max(self._intervals)
    raise Exception("\nERROR: Value Is Greater Than Maximum Element In Points List")
    return
```

and I get something like this:

```
33
[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
100
True
```

So, the value is 33, then I print the list, then the max of that list as the code did.  Plainly, 33 is not > 100, so the last line I test that, but it returns that it is?  How is this possible?  I'm losing my grasp on reality trying to figure out why.  It's probably something overly obvious I just can't see.

Comment: the `return` statement after the `raise` statement is redundant since `raise` would stop the function anyways.

Comment: The assumption is incorrect. Use the actual values in an isolated/minimal test-case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely having `value` be a string `'33'` instead of the int `33`.

For Example:

```
>>> '33' > 100
True
```

The reason for this is when comparing two non-numerical objects that aren't the same type (int and string), the comparison is performed by comparing the names of the types. Since 'int' < 'string', any int is less than any string. This is no longer the case in python3.

Comment: Use `print repr(value)` to check if that is what is happening.

Comment: This is one of the big things that Python 3 fixes.

Comment: That was exactly it.  I can't believe I missed that.  I was close when I was thinking I had to cast it to an int because there might be some float funny business, but it didn't occur to me that I actually grab the value as a string because the json I get back puts them that way.

Comment: I'll accept in 3 mins.  Does that timer exist to prevent rep boosting?

Comment: @linus72982: See [Time limit on accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50697)